# NullReferenceException Debugging

Tags: c#, openxml, nullreferenceexception

Not a duplicate asking for debugging help, not what a Null Reference exception is.

My program is used to loop through an excel file and grab values.

In this section:

```
foreach (Data data in DataL)
     {
         if (data.Columns.Contains(GetColumnName(h.CellReference)[0]))
         {  
             if (h.CellValue.InnerText == " ")
             {
                 data.Items.Add(" ");
             }
             else
             {
                 data.Items.Add(GetCellV(h, ssT));
             }
```

The Program holds a list DataL of Data objects.
Each data object has a list of items, if a cell meets the criterion it is added to the list.

However when my program reaches this point it throws me a NullReferenceException, I know this should mean my Data objects were declared and never instantiated like: `Data foo = new Data();`

[image: Showing Null exception popup]

The picture below shows that my Data List is not empty and holds the one data objected that has been created.

[image: Data count = 1]

What is causing the exception? Is it because the object is instantiated in a different method, and is then local there?

Full code (without GUI): http://rextester.com/OIV93602

Stack Trace

[image: Stack Trace]

Comment: But is the data item a null, or a real object? Next to the line that says "count = 1", click the little triangle.

Comment: its real, its been made and has properties assigned to it

Comment: If one property is null does it make the Object null?

Comment: Can you include the stack trace for the exception, please?

Comment: @JackMiller No, one null property does not make an entire object null. Is the type of DataL `List<Data>`?

Comment: What do you see if you put `DataL[0]` in the Watch window?

Comment: added Stack Trace

Comment: Yes DataL is `public List<Data> DataL = new List<Data>();`